# How can ı fix Case expressions must be constant

Tags: flutter, dart

[I need to use tr() for translate but someting went wrong is there anyone help me][1]

Problem:Case expressions must be constant.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQv3F.jpg

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code in question as text (in a code snippet), rather than using screenshots. See here for more info on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a switch statement with dynamic values in the cases - The value must be known at compile-time.

If you need something similar with dynamic values, you can use `if-else` statements:

```dart
// For example:
if (homeButton.name == "Duyurular".tr()) {
  // Do something
} else if (homeButton.name == "SomethingElse".tr()) {
  // Do something else
}
```